# Difference between instantiation and initialization in servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

I was literally confused what happens when a container calls a servlet.

Can someone help me with how the instantiating and initializing works in servlets when a container calls it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to load servlet container need to first [instantiate](http://java.boot.by/wcd-guide/ch01s04.html) servlet class and then before using it, servlet need to be initialize properly

> After the servlet object is instantiated, the container must initialize the servlet before it can handle requests from clients. Initialization is provided so that a servlet can read persistent configuration data, initialize costly resources (such as JDBC connections), and perform other one-time activities.

In general Java class need to be loaded into class loader and then sometimes class can also have initialization code to be executed before it's used.